# calling servlet from php page using ajax

Tags: java, php, ajax, servlets

i am trying to get response from servlet page and displaying alert on success. but its show me error always. i am not able to figure it out.

My ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#srch").click(function() {
 var txt1 = $("#store-qsearch").val();
 alert(txt1)
 $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/searchengine/SearchDataServlet',
            data : 'val='+txt1,
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(response) {
                alert("Success");
                // create an empty div in your page with some id
            },
            error: function(){ alert("error");

            }
        });
});
                       });
```

My servlet code:

```
public class SerachDataServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String searchkey = request.getParameter("val").toString();
    SearchInput searchinput = new SearchInput();
    searchinput.searchkeys = searchkey;

    System.out.println(searchkey);
    SearchParser searchparser = new SearchParser();
    searchparser.searchData(searchkey);


    PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
    output.println("successs");


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line `data : 'val='+txt1,` to `data: { val: txt1},`

see this for [example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for you reply but it doesn't response success

Comment: @Mayur wait for 5 minutes, I am busy with my work.i will help you as soon i complete my work

Comment: @Mayur Have you configured your web.xml properly?

Comment: @Mayur replace this `http://localhost:8080/searchengine/SearchDataServlet` with `SearchDataServlet` and tell me

Comment: i got it i was getting the error bcoz i am calling ajax from another port instead 8080 and also access.

Comment: i have to just add this: response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");